# Policy can't acess User in Delete/Patch Route

Tags: laravel, crud

When i call my Api Route with the GET Http-Verb it will return me my user. If i call it with the DELETE or PATCH Route it returns null.

I add the Policy to the complete Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Shoppingcart;
use Validator;
use Response;

class ShoppingcartController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->authorizeResource(Shoppingcart::class, 'shoppingcart');
        }


    ...

    public function destroy()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then i 'die and dump' the user in the Policy:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Shoppingcart;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ShoppingcartPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before(?User $user, $ability)
    {
        dd($user);
    }

    public function update(User $user, Shoppingcart $shoppingcart)
    {
    }

    public function delete(User $user, Shoppingcart $shoppingcart)
    {
    }
}
```

I authenticate my Request in the Header and i registerd the Policy in the `AuthServiceProvider.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authentication for Web and API is different. The cookies that are set in the frontend, is not considered at the API.

I needed to register the Auth Middleware also to the API Routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
    Route::apiResource('/shoppingcarts', 'API\ShoppingcartController');
});
```